# Type.MakeGenericType()でTypeLoadExceptionがスローされる場合がある

Tags: c#, .net

型判定の為に、開いた(オープン)ジェネリック型から閉じた(クローズド)ジェネリック型の`Type`を作成しようとすると、一部の型を引数にした時に`TypeLoadException`が発生する。

ドキュメントには`TypeLoadException`例外が発生することは記載されていない。
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=netcore-3.1

#### 再現コード

```cs
var typeParam = typeof(ArgIterator); // 実際はtypeParamは様々な型に対して行う。
_ = typeof(IEquatable<>).MakeGenericType(typeParam);
```

#### 例外メッセージ

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'The generic type 'System.IEquatable`1' was used with an invalid instantiation in assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.'
```

#### 環境

.NET Core 3.1 および .NET Framework 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

仕様と思われる。
下記のコードはC#ではコンパイルエラー(CS0306)になる。

```cs
class C : IEquatable<ArgIterator>
{
    public bool Equals(ArgIterator other) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

ref-like型構造体は、ジェネリック型引数にできないという制約がある。

.NET Coreでは、`MakeGenericType`の引数に渡す前に`Type.IsByRefLike`プロパティを調べ、`true`の場合は`MakeGenericType`を呼び出さないようにすることで回避可能である。

.NET Frameworkでは`Type.IsByRefLike`が無いため、個々の型を弾くか、`try-catch`でスキップする必要があると思われる。